# Powershell Filesize and Extension statistics after Get-ChildItem

Tags: arrays, powershell

what i do is to search files and write some of them with their absoulte path in a file.
now after this searching i want some statistics, like extensions, filesize...

So i need to read the file.txt and get these informations and after all are done, it should show the statistic. It doesnt work yet...

I think i have to store the information in arrays so i can group them later.

```
$directory="d:\file.txt"

get-content $directory|foreach {
MISSING PART?!

Get-ChildItem -Path $_ |

#Get only files
Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |

#Group by extension
Group-Object Extension |

#Get data
Select-Object @{n="Extension";e={$_.Name -replace '^\.'}}, @{n="Size (MB)";e={[math]::Round((($_.Group | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB), 2)}}, Count}
```

do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you are wanting.  You are removing almost all object properties once you hit the "Group-object".  Are you wanting individual file info?

Answer (score 0):

I see you got this code from [Determine recursively both COUNT and SUM of all extensions in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616634/determine-recursively-both-count-and-sum-of-all-extensions-in-a-folder) .

I'm guessing you are modifying it so that instead of a path, you can do different locations based on what is in the text file.  In that case, this works:

```
#Get all items
Get-ChildItem -Path (Get-content C:\Users\krla226\Desktop\file.txt) |
#Get only files
Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
#Group by extension
Group-Object Extension |
#Get data
Select-Object @{n="Extension";e={$_.Name -replace '^\.'}}, @{n="Size (MB)";e={[math]::Round((($_.Group | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB), 2)}}, Count
```

All I changed from the answer on the other post was instead of a directory, I used Get-Content to pull the files paths from the text file.